# I get an error with moving files to different folders

Tags: php, file, directory, rename, move

i have this script that is meant to move a file from one folder to another but i get an error,:

```
    $photo= $_POST['camera']; // i.e. 45647.jpg

   //move file to userpics/ folder

    rename ("../uploads/$photo", "../userpics/$photo");
```

but i get this error:

```
Warning: rename(/uploads/1czcec43s.jpg\n,/userpics/1czcec43s.jpg\n) [function.rename]: No error in .. on line 24
```

Comment: Is the file moved even though a notice is raised?

Comment: Side note: You have a line break in your file names (in `$photo`). It is probably better to remove them...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your filenames are containing linebreaks `\n`.  This may well be the source of the error.  Try calling [`trim`](http://php.net/trim):

```
$photo = trim($_POST['camera']); // i.e. 45647.jpg
rename ("../uploads/$photo", "../userpics/$photo");
```

Also, for goodness sake add some sanity checking to your code.  Your user could easily put `web/index.php` (for instance) as the contents of `$_POST['camera']` and overwrite your PHP file.

Comment: thanks its works :)) can i still escape the $photo, before i insert it into the database!!

Comment: Escaping it won't help. You should write a regular expression to define what you accept as a filename. Something like `/^\w\.jpg$/i` should be sufficient -- alphanumeric characters, no spaces, with underscores, followed by `.jpg`, case-insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

There are an \n (linefeed) at the end of the used POST parameter. Have you tried remove it?

Notice: the presented code is highly vulnerable.